# Android: back button does not kill the main process

Tags: android, button, back

I am using a static variable in an activity in android (it is not the main activity). But when I go to the main activity and I press the back button, the static value remains the same. The back button does not kill the main process. Why?

Comment: Actually the variables remain in the memory, until your app is either force closed or force stopped(in the manage applications).Exiting the app doesn't mean you are killing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the back button destroys the *activity*, **not** the *application*.  All activities are part of an application that is running in a Dalvik VM.  The *application* is still there, running  (even if all activities have been destroyed), until the system decides that it needs resources and kills the process.

As such, your static member will remain in memory as long as the process/app is running.

If you try running some memory-intensive application or closing the running application with some task manager, you may see the static value reset.

Comment: So it sounds like it totally depends in what class the static variable is defined.  From the original post the static variable was defined in an activity which one would think would have been destroyed per the above.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this,

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
        {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: finish(); kills the application?

Comment: try calling System.exit(0); after finish()

Comment: @user1471575: as CSmith mentioned, you can use both, there are do the same thing

Comment: edited answer... actually finish() does not kill the task, it remains running until killed by Android.  Though this solution may be disconcerting to your users.  If you really just need some state re-initialized, do that instead

Comment: @CSmith System.exit(0) is not a good thing to do. Because if you are doing any file read/write options meants, the data will be lost and the temporary data may also lost.

Comment: @Aerrow agreed, I recommend they just re-initialize their state, which seems to be the heart of the question ("the static values remain the same").  This is best done during the main activity onCreate() method.

Answer (score 1):

The user pressing the back button to navigate off of the main activity does not guarantee that the activity will be destroyed.  It just moves your UI (activity) to not being seen.  Refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

Update:

Below are some snippets of text from that second web page:
From the Figure 1 text:
“When the user leaves your activity, the system calls onStop() to stop the activity (1). If the user returns while the activity is stopped, the system calls onRestart() (2), quickly followed by onStart() (3) and onResume() (4). Notice that no matter what scenario causes the activity to stop, the system always calls onPause() before callingonStop().”

And “Note: Because the system retains your Activity instance in system memory when it is stopped, …”

And: “When your activity receives a call to the onStop() method, …. Once your activity is stopped, the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system memory. In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app process without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback, …. “

All of the above demonstrate that when the user leaves your activity (by the back button in your scenario), that it is not necessarily destroyed.  It is only initially stopped.

Comment: According to : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html: When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed) and the previous activity resumes (the previous state of its UI is restored). This means that he activity will be destroyed.!!

Comment: From the same link that I gave: If the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the stack and destroyed. The previous activity in the stack is resumed. ""When an activity is destroyed, the system does not retain the activity's state.""

Comment: Interesting.  I cannot counter that statement.

Comment: I am really confused! when I press the back button from the main activity, it means that the activity is destroyed. But it is not what happen with me!